# Modify the line style for matplot.pyplot.plot() of a Pandas DataFrame crosstab()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

For the following dataframe, **I am unclear how to set display parameters for an individual line in a crosstab plot.** For example, if I want to assign line 4 a heavier weight or specific color. Reviewing the [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) documentation, as well as a number of tutorials, and I'm unclear how to adjust one of the several lines when they are plotted from a dataframe crosstab. I see how to include elements like `xlabel` or `title`, but how to alter the plotting of individual categories remains elusive. If I was calling `plot()` once for each line, then I can envision how to adjust the line on that call. However, plot is called only once and the different lines are counts by category, and I am very puzzled how to proceed. Do I need to somehow apply `for c in category`, or make a list of the categories and slice it? Any insight is much appreciated.

### Minimal Example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'year':np.random.randint(2008,2020,1000),
                   'category':np.random.choice(np.arange(10),size=1000,p=np.arange(10)/sum(np.arange(10)))})

pd.crosstab(df['year'],df['category']).plot(linewidth=1)
plt.title('matplotlib.pyplot of crosstabed Pandas DataFrame')
plt.legend(loc=1, fontsize = 'small', title='Categories')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Count');
```

### Sample Plot

[image]

### Solution

```
# Assign initial plot to axes
ax = pd.crosstab(df['year'],df['category']).plot(linewidth=1)

# Modify axes elements
ax.set(title = 'matplotlib.pyplot of crosstabed Pandas DataFrame',
       xlabel = 'Year',
       ylabel = 'Count')
ax.lines[3].set_linewidth(4)
plt.legend(loc=1, fontsize = 'small', title='Categories')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `lines` from the `Axes` and then modify the one in question:

```
ax = pd.crosstab(df['year'],df['category']).plot(linewidth=1)

ax.lines[3].set_linewidth(4)
```

[image]

I'd add the legend at the end:

```
ax = pd.crosstab(df['year'],df['category']).plot(linewidth=1, legend=False)
ax.lines[3].set_linewidth(4)
ax.legend()
```

[image]